# Disable all the app (share/action) extensions and configure required extensions ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-app-extension

I have the following questions, regarding app extensions in ios.

**Question 1)**
I have an requirement, where I want to enable Print and Download options for my app. When I use App extension (Either Action/Share), I am getting all other options for sharing in social media. (My app doesn't encourage sharing data to social media). If I use `excludedActivityTypes`, I can list out the available social media apps *(few of them, I can refer from [here](http://johnszumski.com/blog/excluding-third-party-apps-from-ios-8-share-sheet))* in that and proceed. But in future, if a new app is installed with share extension enabled, new app's extension can be found in my app. Then the same problem happens.

Is there a way to enable only Print and Download options using app extensions? or any other way to achieve these two functionalities ?

**Question 2)**

Is there a way to disable share extension pane itself and enable the action extension alone?

Thanks in advance.